# Sharepoint 2010 Export-SPWeb does it affect the site you run it on

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If I run Export-SPWeb against a share point site does it has an affect on the site apart from slowing it down potential. can people still read and edit the site?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes people can still use (read/update) it depending on which parameters you specify.

You can prevent access by using `GradualDelete` parameter. When this parameter is used, the site collection is marked as deleted, which immediately prevents any further access to its content. The data in the deleted site collection is then deleted gradually over time by a timer job instead of all at once, which reduces its impact on the performance of farm servers and SQL Server.

The `NoFileCompression` parameter lets you specify that no file compression is performed during the export process. Using this parameter can lower resource usage up to 30% during the export process. Using this parameter will result in a backup folder being created instead of a compressed file. If you use the `NoFileCompression` parameter in the Export-SPWeb command, you must also use it when you import the content by using the Import-SPWeb command.

More on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx).

Comment: I think GradualDelete is for Export-SPSite not Export-SPWeb

Comment: There is no Export-SPSite command - only Export-SPWeb, I assume you're referring to the Backup-SPSite command.  However, neither command has a GradualDelete function:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx